# Angular - Slider/Range component customization

Tags: angular, web, sass, frontend

Can anyone point to a slider component or an idea on how the implement it like the attached picture?
i looked at material slider (mat-slider) that has the thumb label option but can it answer the rest?

Wanted result:

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance!

Tried to use range slider but still not same as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. You can customize this to your range slider.

https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/

Comment: Thanks you will try that. have seen this before but now found the styling guide here https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/blob/master/STYLING.md looks promising. thank you Sir